# How can I run stack haskell app on Mac M1?

Tags: haskell, apple-m1, haskell-stack

When `stack run` there is an error:

```
No setup information found for ghc-8.10.3 on your platform.
This probably means a GHC bindist has not yet been added for OS key 'macosx-aarch64'.
Supported versions: ghc-8.10.5, ghc-8.10.6, ghc-8.10.7, ghc-9.0.2, ghc-9.2.1, ghc- 
9.2.2, ghc-9.2.3
```

But `ghci` works well, how is it possible to fix?

Comment: Looks like the package is configured for a different ghc version than the one you are using. Look at the `stack.yaml` or the `cabal` file for the version that it is using.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, m1 mac requires at least ghc-8.10.5, but you are using ghc-8.10.3. It may be because your project's `stack.yaml` specified ghc-8.10.3, try to change it to 8.10.7 to resolve it. Or select a lts version as an alternative(recommend).

From https://www.stackage.org/, LTS-18.28 uses ghc-8.10.7 as default.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

1. In `stack.yaml` set `resolver: ghc-9.2.3`
2. Execute `stack run` under `bash` (`exec bash` in `zsh` terminal)